# Counting the rows of multiple distinct columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to count the number of rows that have distinct values in both of the columns "a" and "b" in my Sybase ISQL 9 database.

What I means is, the following dataset will produce the answer "4":

```
a b
```

1 9
2 9
3 8
3 7
2 9
3 7

Something like the following syntax would be nice:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a, b) FROM MyTable
```

But this doesn't work.

I do have a solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
  (SELECT a, b 
     FROM MyTable 
    WHERE c = 'foo'
    GROUP BY a, b) SubTable
```

But I was wondering if there is a neater way of constructing this query?

Comment: c = 'foo' was just to show that there were other rows in the table that I'm not interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concatenate a and b together into 1 string like this (TSQL, hopefully something very similar in Sybase:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(STR(a) + ',' + STR(b)))
FROM @YourTable
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if a or b are string columns containing commas

Comment: True, I was assuming they were integers. If they are strings, then any delimiter could be used...something like "{RANDOM_DELIM}". Just a case of deciding on a suitable delimiter I guess

Comment: The data that I'm interested in are stored as ints so this method works - I've just tested it!

Comment: While you're at it, test performance as well. I think this solution will be slower than what you originally tried it with.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM MyTable)
```

For more information on why this can't be done in a simpler way (besides concatenating strings as noted in a different answer), you can refer to the this Google Answers post: [Sql Distinct Count](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/235114.html).