# Count rows with multiple aggreagate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

I have a test table to demonstrate the issue:

```
Id  NetworkId   CountryCode
1       1           de
2       2           de
3       2           de
4       2           de
5       1           us
6       1           us
7       1           us
8       2           us
```

I need to output something like this:

```
NetworkId   CountryCode    DistCount
    1           de              1
    2           de              3
    1           us              3
    2           us              1
```

### Attempted Queries

I looked for several answers on SO and I wasn't able to find exactly what I need. Here is the first related question and the queries I tried: [Counting the rows of multiple distinct columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199131/counting-the-rows-of-multiple-distinct-columns)

**Query:**

```
SELECT NetworkId, CountryCode, COUNT(*) as DistCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NetworkId, CountryCode FROM TestTable) AS FOO
GROUP BY NetworkId, CountryCode
```

**Results in:**

```
NetworkId   CountryCode    DistCount
    1           de              1
    1           us              1
    2           de              1
    2           us              1
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(STR(NetworkId) + ',' + STR(CountryCode)))
FROM TestTable
```

**Results in:**

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.
```

---

I also tried the answers in this question: [How can I count distinct multiple fields without repeating the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664043/how-can-i-count-distinct-multiple-fields-without-repeating-the-query)

Query:

```
SELECT 
   NetworkId, 
   CountryCode,
   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NetworkId, CountryCode) as DistCount
FROM TestTable
GROUP BY NetworkId, CountryCode
```

Result:

```
NetworkId   CountryCode    DistCount
    1           de              1
    1           us              1
    2           de              1
    2           us              1
```

As you can tell, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this... I would think it should be relatively simple, but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Id is unique and not null within TestTable (which it will be if it is the primary key), then this query will return the result set you specified:

```
SELECT NetworkId, CountryCode, Count(1) AS DistCount
  FROM TestTable 
 GROUP BY NetworkId, CountryCode
 ORDER BY NetworkId, CountryCode
```

However, if the `Id` column is not unique, and what you want is a count of distinct non-null `Id` values within each group, you can add the DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT NetworkId, CountryCode, Count(DISTINCT Id) AS DistCount
  FROM TestTable 
 GROUP BY NetworkId, CountryCode
 ORDER BY NetworkId, CountryCode
```

Given your sample data, both queries will return the same result. There will be a difference only if you have duplicate `Id` values within a group.

Comment: @Lirik: I typically use `COUNT(1)` when what I want to return is a count of rows. Note that this returns a result equivalent to `SUM(1)`, and that makes sense conceptually, because for each row that is included in the group, we're essentially incrementing a row counter by 1. When we use some other expression, e.g. `COUNT(Id)`, it's only going to increment the counter for non-NULL values. Which is equivalent to `SUM(IF Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1)`. When we add the `DISTINCT` keyword e.g. `COUNT(DISTINCT Id)`, now we're only incrementing the row counter when a non-NULL value is not already include

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm mistaken, this would work:

```
SELECT NetworkId, CountryCode, COUNT(Id) as DistCount
FROM TestTable
GROUP BY NetworkId, CountryCode
```

Comment: OK, that works... let me see if it work in my actual query, because things are a bit more complicated there.

Comment: Here's a backing [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce89b/3) too.  (argh, just beaten)

Comment: @Lirik - If your query is considerably more complicated, you may need to show us the rest of it, so we can help you better.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse It's a much bigger query, but it involves too much other stuff that's not relevant. This was the key part I was missing and it works like a charm now!